# How to get int Month, Day, And Year in String format "EEE, MMM d, yyyy"

Tags: java, android

I'm hoping you guys can help me on this. When i use DatePicker, i display my date in "EEE, MMM d, yyyy" format.

```
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy").format(cal.getTime());
            editTextStartDate.setText(strDate);
```

But after setting the date i will process the data, And I need the data to be formatted into "dd/mm/yyyy" so that i can use it by splitting it:

```
    String startDate = editTextStartDate.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!startDate.isEmpty()) {
        String getTo[] = startDate.split("/");
        getToDateYear = Integer.parseInt(getTo[2]);
        getToDateMonth = Integer.parseInt(getTo[1]);
        getToDateDay = Integer.parseInt(getTo[0]);

        toTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, getToDateYear);
        toTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, getToDateMonth-1);
        toTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, getToDateDay);
    }
```

What is the best way for me to do this? Hopefully you guys can help teach and guide me. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will not be any **/** in `String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy").format(cal.getTime());`

So, Your **String getTo[]** will not have any Array Output.

So Solution is below to convert your Date format to another format as below:

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
Date sourceDate = null;
try {
    sourceDate = sourceDateFormat.parse(startDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String targetdatevalue= targetFormat.format(sourceDate);
```

So ***targetdatevalue*** will be your desired output.